# Turn loggin back on for Selenium Geckodriver

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver

I'm using Jsch library to make a SSH connection to my Linux machine to execute a few commands right before I use Selenium with Geckodriver. I noticed that I don't see any errors even if an element does not exist on the webpage.

After some investigation I found out that the if the following code gets executed before running my Selenium test, then all the log messages from Geckodriverstop stop being displayed

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
```

How can I enable the log messages after the above command has executed?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [ChannelExec](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html) you should use [setErrStream(OutputStream out,boolean dontclose)](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html#setErrStream-java.io.OutputStream-)

> public void setErrStream(OutputStream out,
>                            boolean dontclose)
>
> Sets the error stream. The standard error output of the remote process
>   will be sent to this stream.
>
> Parameters:
>       dontclose - if true, we do not close the stream on Channel.disconnect(com.jcraft.jsch.Session).

In this way you can chose if the System.err have to be closed when you disconnect the channel.

If you use:

> public void setErrStream(OutputStream out)
>
> Sets the error stream. The standard error output of the remote process
>   will be sent to this stream. The stream will be closed on
>   Channel.disconnect(com.jcraft.jsch.Session).

will be always closed.